# An equation with a parameter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, parametric, absolute-value

Given the equation $(|x+1|+|x-a|)^2-2(|x+1|+|x-a|)+4a-4a^2=0$ find all possible $a$ such that this equation has only one solution.

I wanted to solve it like this:

$(|x+1|+|x-a|)^2-2(|x+1|+|x-a|)+4a-4a^2=0 \iff(|x+1|+|x-a|-2a)(|x+1|+|x-a| +2a-2)=0$

Then, since both equations in parentheses have to be equal we need to solve $2a-2=-2a$, which will give $a=\frac{1}{2}$.

Plugging $\frac{1}{2}$ in the equation will give $(|x+1|+|x-\frac{1}{2}|-1)^2=0$ and if we solve this, we won't get a case where we have 1 solution, hence there can't be such an $a$.

Is it a wrong solution? I was told it is, but I don't understand why. Also, the answer is correct.

Comment: You forgot to consider cases, when only one of the parenthesis has solutions.

Comment: @Kaster I don't really understand what you mean by that. Do we need to solve each equation in the parentheses separately and then intersect the solutions or together like I did?

Comment: It is possible that expression in one of the parenthesis doesn't have a solution, since it involves absolute values. For example, what's the solution of $|x-1| = -2$ ?

Comment: @Kaster so what if it doesn't? Then we don't need that case. I don't understand what you mean exactly, sorry, I know that |x-1| can't be -2, but I still don't get your point.

Comment: It leaves you with only one of the parenthesis, which also involves absolute values, so that other expression might have one, two or no solutions. So, it's not just making solutions of the expressions in each parenthesis equal. In other words, you need to consider more cases, not just that one case you described in your question.

Comment: @Kaster so I need to solve both parentheses independently and then intersect solutions?

Comment: it's not an intersection, it's a union though.

Comment: @Kaster but how can we solve them separately, if we are supposed to open the absolute value expression with the same sign in both parentheses?  What if in the left one I open it with minus, and the right one with plus and they will be equal?

Comment: @Kaster finally understood what you were saying, I didn't know that if one parenthesis has a solution and the other doesn't then the equation has one solution, I always thought that an equation (x-c1)(x-c2)=0 has one solution iff c1=c2. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $f(x)=|x+1|+|x-a|$ is symmetric around $2x=a-1$ so that there are always at least two $x$ achieving the same $f(x)$, and solutions always go in pairs (or more; actually the function is flat between $1$ and $a$).

The only way to have a single solution would be when $a=-1$ so that the flat reduces to a single point, but this does not work as $x=-2,-1,0$ are three solutions.

Comment: why |x-1+|x-a|? where did |x-1| come from?

Comment: @paulpaul1076: from a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT :**

$ Let : (|x+1| + |x-a|) = y$.

Then your equation becomes : $y^2 - 2y + 4a - 4a^2$.

Solve that and then define the $y$ you find as your starting form $(|x+1| + |x-a|) $ and then find the $a$ that this equation has one solution.

Comment: That's exactly what OP did.

Comment: Yea, I've already done that, don't understand your hint

Comment: It's missing steps, letting a $y$ parameter be an expression means you must define strictly that $y$ which wasn't done and that's why I say "define the y..".

Comment: Kaster just added a comment to your question (consider cases), that is what I mean by the word "define y". :)